# Creating a new div for each element for two different arrays using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to create a dialog box with images and text. I have an array of images and names. I want to create a new div for each image and name. Not sure if I'm iterating the items correctly and if and why this doesn't work. Right now, I'm getting a syntax error and the 'i' is `undefined` when I run this code. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
var itemImages = ["image1", "image2", "image3"]
var itemNames = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]

var message = '<div class="box-cart-products">
<script>$(itemImages).each(function(i, e){$(".box-cart-
products").append("<div class="box-cart-product"><div class="box-cart-
product-image"><img src="'+itemImages[i]+'"/></div><div 
class="box-cart-product-name"><span>'+itemNames[i]+'</span></div>
</div>")})</script></div>'

$(message).dialog()
```

Here's the breakdown of my message variable.

```
<div class="box-cart-products">
 <script>
  $(itemImages).each(function(i, e){
   $(".box-cart-products").append(
    "<div class="box-cart-product">
      <div class="box-cart-product-image"><img src="'+itemImages[i]+'"/></div>
      <div class="box-cart-product-name"><span>'+itemNames[i]+'</span></div>
    </div>"
   )
  })
 </script>
</div>
```

Comment: I am confused. Do you want the final message to contain the part **itemImages[i]** ? Or do you want it to be replaced before getting printed on the page?

Comment: Here you should start with a single quote "<div class="box-cart-product"> and the last double quotes </div>" should be single also.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, I want the final message to contain the actual image that's stored in my variable. I'm trying to iterate the array of images and show it in my dialog box. 

I changed the double quotes to single. Now I'm getting the error - "Uncaught Syntax: Unexpected token class" and it's pointing at the new div I want to create  "<div class="box-cart-product". Am I not allowed to create a new class when I'm creating a new div in the append function? I googled it but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: BTW: I just started using StackOverflow and I'm so appreciative of this community and how quickly people are answering. It's awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue just had to do with `'` vs `"`.  Make sure when you have to mix and match them, use one to start/stop your string and the other inside the string (or you can escape the characters but I find that more difficult to read).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-cart-products"></div>

<script>
  var itemImages = ["image1", "image2", "image3"]
  var itemNames = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]

  $(itemImages).each(function(i, e) {
    $(".box-cart-products").append(
      '<div class="box-cart-product"> <div class="box-cart-product-image"><img src="' + itemImages[i] + '"/> </div> <div class="box-cart-product-name"> <span>' + itemNames[i] + '</span></div></div>'
    )
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I'm not getting any more syntax errors. However, my images and names are not showing up in the dialog box. When I checked the html, it shows the code that I wrote within the <script></script> tags, instead of creating new divs for the images and names. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @C.Yee updated my answer to use inline script (this is generally frowned upon unless there is a specific reason to use inline script tags).  Without seeing how your code is currently written, I could only guess why it isn't working, as it is working as expected above.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help!